# Apache Spark duplicate key even after groupBy and aggregate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

What I am trying to do:

1. select a 4 column row as only 2 columns - 1 key column col_0 and other col_info as concatenated other columns with '|' as delimiter.
2. group by a key column (col_0).
3. aggregate the col_info by concatenating con_info columns by ',' delimiter.
4. insert into some other aggregate table.

```
    val invDF = spark.read.jdbc(
        jdbcUrl,
        "myschema.mytable",
        connectionProperties
    )

    val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())

    val agged = invDF
        .select($"col_0", concat_ws("|", $"col_1", $"col_2", $"col_3") as "col_info")
        .groupBy($"col_0")
        .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"col_info")) as "col_info")
        .select($"col_0", $"col_info", lit(date) as "modified_ts")

    agged.write
        .option("truncate", "true")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "myschema.myaggtable", connectionProperties)
```

Since, I assume now that col_0 will be unique as I grouped by that, surprisingly, I am getting the primary key violation error:

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__xxxx'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'myschema.myaggtable'. The duplicate key value is (yyyy).

Comment: Is there data in the table already which could cause the issue?

Comment: Did you try to find that duplicate keys actually? Are they indeed the same? What is the type of `col_0`

Comment: Save mode is append, could you please try it with SaveMode.Overwrite. The key might be present in table as @Shaido-ReinstateMonica has already commented above.

Comment: I have already selected the option("truncate", "true") which should truncate the table before appending the data.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the truncate option. Thanks, I'll try that and see the result.